# Adding custom checkbox to WooCommerce product variation options

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, backend, product, hook-woocommerce

I've added a custom field to variable products in the WC admin. Using the action:

```
action_woocommerce_variation_options_pricing
```

But it's displaying in the wrong location. I'd ideally like the checkbox to display in the options section above. But i can't find the action to move it there.

I've spent ages looking through the WC docs, but can't find the correct action. Does anyone know the correct way for me to move the checkbox to this location?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_variation_options` action hook, to add a custom checkbox to the WooCommerce product variation options.

(Copied from: `views/html-variation-admin.php`, line 188)

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', $loop, $variation_data, $variation ); ?>
```

So you get:

```php
// Add checkbox
function action_woocommerce_variation_options( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    $is_checked = get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_mycheckbox', true );

    if ( $is_checked == 'yes' ) {
        $is_checked = 'checked';
    } else {
        $is_checked = '';     
    }

    ?>
    <label class="tips" data-tip="<?php esc_attr_e( 'This is my data tip', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Checkbox:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox variable_checkbox" name="_mycheckbox[<?php echo esc_attr( $loop ); ?>]"<?php echo $is_checked; ?>/>
    </label>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'action_woocommerce_variation_options', 10, 3);

// Save checkbox
function action_woocommerce_save_product_variation( $variation_id, $i ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['_mycheckbox'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['_mycheckbox'][$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_mycheckbox', 'yes' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_mycheckbox', 'no' ); 
    }       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'action_woocommerce_save_product_variation', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Ah of course. I was overseeing the fact that i needed to go a step back from woocommerce_variation_options_pricing and just use the woocommerce_variation_options action. Thanks very much for pointing me in the right direction. You can ignore the "Swatches Settings" I think it was throwing you off track being highlighted orange. I can confirm the screenshot was on the tab above "Variations".